# mod rewrite old url to new url, change parameter name but keep value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I change
http://www.domain.ca/directory/file.php?oldkey=2087
to 
http://www.domain.ca/directory/?id=2087

I want to update the URL to remove the old filename AND change the parameter key BUT keep the value the same.

I have tried many combinations but so far nothing I've tried gives me this result. All of my searches yield solutions to different problems and changing queries into directories, or changing param values, but not the param keys.

Most recent attempts:

```
#Redirect 302 (.*)file\.php\?oldkey$ http://www.domain.ca/directory/?id$1
```

and

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.ca/directory/file\.php?oldkey=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.ca/directory/id=$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)deal=(&|$)
RewriteRule ^oldkey=$ /$0?id= [R=302,L]
```

I am using 302 for now until I have it working then will change to 301 for permanence.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I've tried a few more versions that seemed promising but still to no avail. AM I on the right track hopefully?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^oldkey=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/directory/$ /directory/directory2/?id=%1 [NC,L] #R=302 - for now
```

Nothing happens though. It's like the rule is being ignored. SHouldn't it fire if the key is present?
I've even also prepending the above with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} oldkey
```

to check if the key is present in the query string.

Comment: 1. That is not a host name. 2. RewriteRule only looks at the path component of the URL, not the query string.

Comment: 1. Yes, I know. I tried modifying it further to see if I could get a different result.
2. What about when it is preceded by RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}?

Comment: Why the down vote? Nobody has asked a question like this. I'm new to Mod Rewrite but I am trying to figure it out and hopefully others will be able to use the answers here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^oldkey=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^directory/file\.php$ /directory/?id=%1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: This seems to be ignored when I try it - replacing the variables with my real site data of course.

Comment: @acarito is the "oldkey" limited to only numbers (like in your example) or can it be anything? If it can be anything, you need to change the `[0-9]+` to `[^&]+`.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Lin, good to know. It is just limited to numbers though.

Comment: Turns out this was what I needed. My current script had an L at the end for the Wordpress portion which was preventing any further RewriteRules from firing. Now the last rule has the L and all works well. Thanks!

Comment: @acarito oh, if you have wordpress routing rules, you may want to place those rules *at the very end of your htaccess file*. Redirects **must happen before any routing** otherwise, the routing happens, and any redirection is skipped.

Comment: Yes that definitely makes sense. I put my custom redirects after the WordPress ones so that it affects the URL made by WordPress first.  The main change I had to make was to remove {l} from the last RewriteRule of the WordPress portion and stick it on to my last RewriteRule. 
Now it's all happening within 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AND
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Do you see any potential conflicts with this method?
Thanks again